# Unable to compile custom UnityPlayerActivity Unity 2019 package not found

Tags: java, android, macos, unity-game-engine, javac

This question has been asked a few times before, but none of the solutions work for me. I am trying to compile my custom UnityPlayerActivity on macos terminal, and linking to correct classes but still unable to compile the new Activity.

Here's my compile command (broken down in bullets, all the files its pointing to are available.

> ```
> /Applications/Unity/2019.4.0f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/javac BZUnityPlayerActivity.java    
> -bootclasspath /Applications/Unity/2019.4.0f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/jre/lib
> -classpath /Applications/Unity/2019.4.0f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Classes/classes.jar:/Applications/Unity/2019.4.0f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platforms/android-28/android.jar
> ```

And it throws following error:

> ```
> BZUnityPlayerActivity.java:3: error: package com.unity3d.player does not exist
> import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
>                          ^
> BZUnityPlayerActivity.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
> public class RGUnityPlayerActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
> ```